# PYTHON - How to change data entry state to normal?

Tags: python, tkinter, calendar, state, ttkwidgets

I can disable the calendar widget with the 'Disable' button, but if I want to reactivate it, I get the following error:

```
tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-normal"
```

If i try to use the `calendar.config(state="normal")` command, I get the following error:

```
tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-state"
```

```
import tkinter as tk 
import ttkbootstrap as ttk

def disable_calendar():
    calend["state"]="disabled"

def enable_calendar():
    calend["state"]="normal"


root = ttk.Window() 
root.geometry("400x400")

calend =  ttk.DateEntry(bootstyle="primary") 
calend.place(x=10, y=10)     

disableCalendar_button = ttk.Button(text = "Disable", width=10, command=disable_calendar) 
disableCalendar_button.place(x=10, y=50)

enableCalendar_button = ttk.Button(text = "Enable", width=10, command=enable_calendar) 
enableCalendar_button.place(x=100, y=50)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/israel-dryer/ttkbootstrap/blob/master/src/ttkbootstrap/widgets.py) for the ttkbootstrap `DateEntry` widget shows that it inherits from the `ttk.Frame` class, which itself doesn't accept `state` changes. However, it looks like the following states are allowed because `DateEntry` overrides the built-in `configure` method:

- `'disabled'`
- `'readonly'`
- `'invalid'`

As far as I can tell, the default "normal" state is `'readonly'`, but I'm not sure.

```
class DateEntry(ttk.Frame)
...
    def _configure_set(self, **kwargs):
        """Override configure method to allow for setting custom
        DateEntry parameters"""

        if "state" in kwargs:
            state = kwargs.pop("state")
            if state in ["readonly", "invalid"]:
                self.entry.configure(state=state)
            elif state == "disabled":
                self.entry.configure(state=state)
                self.button.configure(state=state)
            else:
                kwargs[state] = state
```